# reshape dataframe from columns to rows and collapse cell values

Tags: r, transformation, reshape2, melt

Here's the challenge i am facing. I am trying to transform this dataset

```
  a    b     c
  100  0     111
  0    137   17
  78   117   91
```

into (column to rows)

```
  col1  col2
  a     100,78
  b     137,117
  c     111,17,91
```

I know I can do this using `reshape` or `melt` function but I am not sure how to collapse and paste the cell values. Any suggestions or pointers is appreciated folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `dplyr` rather than reshape.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Data <- data.frame(a=c(100,0,78),b=c(0,137,117),c=c(111,17,91))

Data %>%
  gather(Column, Value) %>%
  filter(Value != 0) %>%
  group_by(Column) %>%
  summarize(Value=paste0(Value,collapse=', '))
```

The gather function is similar to `melt` in `reshape`. The `group_by` function tells later functions that you want to seperate based off of values in `Column`. Finally `summarize` calculates whatever summary we want for each of the groups. In this case, paste all the terms together.

Which should give you:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Column       Value
   <chr>       <chr>
1      a     100, 78
2      b    137, 117
3      c 111, 17, 91
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a light weight option using `toString()` method to collapse each column to a string and using `stack()` to reshape the result list to your desired output:

```
stack(lapply(df, function(col) toString(col[col!=0])))

#       values ind
#1     100, 78   a
#2    137, 117   b
#3 111, 17, 91   c
```

Answer (score 0):

With `library(data.table)`

```
melt(dt)[, .(value = paste(value[value !=0], collapse=', ')), by=variable]
#  variable       value
# 1:      a     100, 78
# 2:      b    137, 117
# 3:      c 111, 17, 91
```

The data:

```
dt = fread("a    b     c
100  0     111
0    137   17
78   117   91")
```